# Which one is faster: ST_GeomFromText or ST_GeomFromGeoJSON

Tags: mysql, sql, geometry, geospatial, geojson

I am creating a stored procedure on MySQL that will get a few hundred thousand points and make a join using ST_Within, the geometries being compared will be a GeoJSON. I wrote the entire procedure and it was working, however, my tests were made using texts of geometries, and the final procedure needs to use GeoJSONs. The tests using ST_GeomFromText took around 40-50 seconds, and now that I am using GeoJSON and ST_GeomFromGeoJSON, the tests are taking 70-80 seconds. The two tests were using exactly the same data. Is one function faster than the other? Or is there another problem?

p.s.: I had a problem using ST_Envelope, and got the error "st_envelope(GEOMCOLLECTION) has not been implemented for geographic spatial reference systems", so when I read the GeoJSON using ST_Geomfrom GeoJSON, I am also using SRID = 0.

Comment: Suggest you experiment and present your results (including a test case) as an Answer to your Question.

Comment: I would imagine parsing GeoJSON will always take longer as it is a more complex format. I would look at using `ogr2ogr` to import the geojson file to a table before you call the procedure